# Posting a Bundle does not create contained resources

Tags: fhir-server-for-azure

I'm using he OSS FHIR Server and tried posting a Bundle containing a Practioner, Patient and QuestionnaireResponse.  The Bundle itself posted to Cosmos but was not parsed, the individual resources were not created.

I read somethng about posting to "root", still didn't work.

Not sure if i'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [FHIR Wiki](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/bundle.html#rest):

> The Bundle resource type has an end-point like all most other
> resources. This end-point serves the usual interactions. Bundles are
> treated as static resources on the /Bundle end-point (i.e. when a
> batch, transaction, or message is POSTed to /Bundle, it is stored as
> is, and the content is not processed as batch, transaction, or message;
> instead, they are processed like normal resource, with indexing / auditing etc. Performing a GET /Bundle/[location] will return the same
> resource.

In short if you post your bundle to **server.root.url/Bundle** the bundle will be stored 'as is' without being processed, whereas if you post to **server.root.url** then the bundle will be processed as expected, creating contained resources.